# Converting String to Python Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

This code returns a str as the type. Given the format of tasks, how do I convert it into a python dictionary?

```
import json

tasks = '''{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': None}'''

new_tasks = tasks.replace("'", "\"")
new_tasks = new_tasks.replace('None', 'null')

new_tasks = json.dumps(new_tasks)
new_tasks = json.loads(new_tasks)
print(type(new_tasks))
```

Note: I would prefer to not use ast.literal_eval or ast.eval.

Comment: Get rid of the line that calls `json.dumps()`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ast.literal_eval()`? This is precisely what it's intended for.

Comment: Your code will do the wrong thing for `{'None': 'val1'}` or `{'key1': 'None of us are coming'}`

Comment: Please work through the documentation and/or tutorials for the `json` package.  You have the right idea, but you need to learn the usage idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json

tasks = '''{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': None}'''

new_tasks = tasks.replace("'", "\"")
new_tasks = new_tasks.replace('None', 'null')

# new_tasks = json.dumps(new_tasks)
new_tasks = json.loads(new_tasks)
print(type(new_tasks))
```

As Barmar said, the dumps double wraps it in quotation marks

output:

```
<class 'dict'>
```